# magnific-popup open in parent when calling from iframe

Tags: magnific-popup

I have a small iframe on my page. Whe a user clicks a link within that iframe, the content opens in a magnific-popup. But, the popup is only loading within the iframe, not the either page. How would I get the popup to open in the center of the parent (whole page)? I tried adding target="_parent" and target="_top" to the  but they didn't work.

Comment: Did you ever find a way to do this?